# What is the use of withRouter HOC?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am going the tutorial of react-router, where I encountered the topic of withRouter HOC. Why it is provided in the react-router library and how to use it?

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Answer (score 1):

It is needed whenever you want to have access to the `match`, `history` or `location` object of `react-router`. For basic functionality you can get away with `Switch` , `Route` and `Link`, but if you want to implement similar components yourself, or just want to access router functions [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) in `javascript` code, you will have to use `withRouter` or `useRouter` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`withRouter` is a higher-order component provided by `react-router-dom` which gives you access to `history`, `match` and `location` object from `props` of particular object which is wrapped with `withRouter`.